# Return all users from group(s) specified as comma delimited value

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have the following two table scenario:

```
users
id   groups
1    1,2,3
2    2,3
3    1,3
4    3
```

and

```
groups
id
1
2
3
```

How do I return the IDs of all users that belong to group 2 and 1 for example? Should I look into join, a helper group_membership table or function to separate the comma delimited group IDs to get something like this:

```
group_membership
user_id   group_id
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         2
2         3
...       ...
```

Comment: You may want to think about moving to a [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) table structure.

Comment: First: Do you KNOW which group you want to check, or do you want to make a 'general' list? If the first, try 'LIKE %2%'. If the second: Consider creating a intermediary list.

Comment: normalise the table structure then everything will be easier

Comment: I am working on an existing product and cannot normalize the table in this version. LIKE might not work since the group IDs are selected from select list with multiple attribute. I agree, the table should be normalized first, but at this time I need to hack it.

Comment: @todor: Your existing product is broken, why won't you fix it?

Comment: I will normalize the table as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be having a many-to-many relationship between users and groups, (meaning, a user may belong into multiple groups, and a group can hold multiple users).

You do that by having 3 tables:

- **users** - to describe user information.
- **groups** - to describe group information.
- **user_groups** - to describe which users are in which groups.

In the **user_groups**, you should have only 2 columns, **user_id** and **group_id**, each row is a single user belonging in a single group, where repititions on both sides are allowed.

Your example translates into:

```
user_id   group_id
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         2
2         3
3         1
3         3
4         3
```

Then, it's very easy to query all of the users in specific groups, as well as all of the groups as user is in.

This process is also called **[Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)**

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution to your problem is a rearranging of your data.

For this, you need three tables. The users, the groups, and a 'link'-table.

users:

```
user_id
userdata1
```

groups:

```
group_id
groupdata1
```

link

```
user_id
group_id
```

In the link list, you create one dataset for each connection.

So, if user 1 is in groups 2 and 3, the link table will have two entries with the user_id 1. One linking to group_id 2, and one linking to group_id 3.

To get back to your example, the query to get all users from group 2 is:

```
SELECT * FROM users, link WHERE link.user_id = users.user_id AND (group_id = 2 OR group_id = 3);
```

This will output all the users, who are in one of the groups, some as duplicates (those, who are members of both groups). If you want to avoid duplicates, add 'GROUP BY user_id'

Comment: this kind of rearranging is [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @MarcB I never claimed I was inventing the wheel, did I? ;)

Comment: nope. just making note of it in case OP wants to look up more about it.

Comment: Thanks guys! I will go ahead and normalize the structure.

Answer (score 0):

***Except a proper normalisation***, the only usable **hack**, and it is a **hack**, in this situation is using a hack with `LIKE`.

### This is still a slow and horrible practice.

SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM users 
WHERE 
   groups LIKE '%,$group_id,%' 
   OR groups LIKE '%,$group_id' 
   OR groups LIKE '$group_id,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FIND_IN_SET()` MySQL function.